# Simple async image upload for Express?

Tags: javascript, html, express, dom

I'm using a button click to trigger a file input dialog.  Once the file is selected, I'm displaying the thumbnail in a preview.

```
const uploadListener = function() {
  const preview = document.getElementById('preview')
  const uploadBlob = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])
  preview.style.backgroundImage = `url(${ uploadBlob })`;
}

const fileUploader = document.getElementById('fileUpload')
fileUploader.addEventListener('change', uploadListener)
```

From here, what's the easiest way to get the file at `uploadBlob` asynchronously sent (via XMLHttpRequest()?) to my node.js Express server and saved to the server?

I've written this out with a base64 encoded FileReader() in the past, where you have to filter out the metadata, then decode to a binary file and figure out the name + extension on the server, but it was slow and seemed sort of obscure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's misleading to name the variable `uploadBlob` since it's not a blob any more. it's a url, you don't send that to the server.

Basically, append the blob/file to a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), then send the formdata in your ajax request

```
const fd = new FormData()
fd.append('avatar', this.files[0])
// fd.append('avatar', this.files[0], optionalFileName)

fetch(uploadUrl, {method: 'post', body: fd})

/* 
or using XMLHttpRequest:

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest
xhr.open('POST', uploadURL)
xhr.send(fd)
*/
```